# How to fix my while loop conditions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I created a game, in which there is a secret number, and you guess, then the computer guesses. The secret number changes every round. To win, either you or the computer needs to get a score of 2.

I don't know how many rounds it will take, so I loop the game 100 times in a while loop with the condition that the user_Score and computer_Score is not equal to 2,

However, when I run my code, it seems like it just skips the condition, and goes on 100 times, and I don't understand why.

```
while user_score != 2 or computer_score != 2:
    for _ in range(100):
        game()
```

The above code is the part which I am talking about, it is in the near bottom of my code

```
import random

computer_score = 0
user_score = 0 
    
def game():
    global user_score
    global computer_score
   
    secret_number = random.randrange(10)
    while True:
        user_guess = input("Guess a number from 0 - 10:  ")
        if user_guess.isdigit():
            user_guess = int(user_guess)
            if 0 <= user_guess <= 10:
                break
            else:
                print("Enter a valid number from 0 - 10")
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid number from 0 - 10")
    computer_guess = random.randrange(10)
    
    if user_guess == secret_number:
        print("Hooray! You guessed correctly")
        user_score += 1
        print(f"Your score is {user_score}")
    else:
        print("Sorry wrong guess")
    print("Now Player 2's turn")
    
    if computer_guess == secret_number:
        print("Player 2 guessed the correct number!")
        computer_score += 1
        print(f"Player 2's score is {computer_score}")
    else:
        print("Player 2 guesed incorrectly")
    
    print( f" Your score: {user_score}" + "   " + f"Player 2 score: {computer_score}")
game() 
 
 
while user_score != 2 or computer_score != 2:
    for _ in range(100):
        game()

if user_score == 2:
    print(f"Hooray! You won with a score of {user_score} points")
    print(f"Player 2 got {computer_score} points")
elif computer_score == 2:
    print(f"Sorry, you lost. Your score is {user_score}, and Player 2 got {computer_score} points")
print( f" Your final score: {user_score}" + "   " + f"Player 2 final score: {computer_score}" )
```

Comment: You enter the `while` loop because not the `user_score` nor the `computer_score` are 2 and *then* you `for` 100 times (no matter what).

Comment: Try using an `if` inside the `for` loop instead of the `while` outside.

Comment: And you should loop while `user_score != 2` **and**  `computer_score != 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while user_score != 2 or computer_score != 2:
    for _ in range(100):
        game()
```

If a player gets a score of two, that will *not* stop the inner `for` loop.  It's going to loop to 100, because that's what you told it to do.

I'm confused why you need the inner loop at all, though.  Isn't the outer `while` loop enough?

```
while user_score != 2 or computer_score != 2:
    game()
```

Also, wouldn't you want to use `and` here, instead of `or`?  The way this is written, it will only stop if *both* scores are equal to 2.  And if one of the players gets to a score of 3 while the other player has a score of 0 or 1, this loop will *never* exit.

Comment: Hey John, thank you so much, I'm completely new to this, and I'm still learning, but what you said really helped me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It will always show this same fault. Because, at the beginning of the game when 1st round is over, the `for` loop starts iterating and it will continue for 100 times. Best way is to remove the `for` loop and just run the `while` loop.

```python
while user_score != 2 or computer_score != 2:
    game()
```